# Swift NSlayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question... I am really not understand something. 
I have a UIView Class which only create a UITextLabel.. I'm trying to add instances from this class to my Viewcontroller. This is how my UIViewClass look like:

```
    class PostLineItem: UIView {


    var labelText : String!
    var labelHeader : String!

    init(labelText: String , labelHeader: String) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
        self.labelText = labelText
        self.labelHeader = labelHeader
        let tlb = timeLineBlock()
        //tlb.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.addSubview(tlb)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            ])

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        println("required public")
    }


    private func timeLineBlock() -> UIView{

        let viewNew = UIView()
        viewNew.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)


        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 20)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        titleLabel.text = labelHeader
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        viewNew.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        /* IF I NOT COMMENT THIS PART INSTANCE OF THIS CLASS IS NOT SHOWING UP.
        viewNew.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewNew, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewNew, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewNew, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            ])
       */ 

        viewNew.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return viewNew

    }

}
```

And this is my viewController class part where i try to instantiate the PostLineItem instances..

```
 let guideView = UIView()
    guideView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    guideView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    scrollView.addSubview(guideView)

    scrollView.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -30),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:10)
        ])



guideView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


var viewFromAbove = guideView


for post in 1...70 {

    let v = PostLineItem(labelText: "Tst", labelHeader: "Tst2")
    scrollView.addSubview(v)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 15),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                 NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 400)
        ])
    viewFromAbove = v
    }

    scrollView.addConstraints([
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewFromAbove, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10)
    ])
```

As you can see, first of all i create a guidview for the first PostLineItem and then adding the new instances and the constraints.. So..

If i do it this way the instances of the PostLineItem class will be at the same places and hides each others... I think, the NSLAyoutConstaint not effect.

But, as you can see at the commented part of the code, if i create a simple UILabel the constraints work fine, and all of the UILabel instances will be under each others..

UPDATE:
after i adding all of written in the answer it's look like this.. :(

[image]

That little red rect is my PostLineItem instance.. :(

UPDATED - all  code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm thinking you might be adding the constraints to the wrong views.  For instance, the `guideView` height constraint should be added to the `guideView`, and not the `scrollView`.  I would suggest instead you use the new way of activating constraints.  Instead of adding them to the views, you just call the `activateConstraints` class method on `NSLayoutConstraint`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 24),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:4)
            ])
```

and

```
NSLayoutConstraints.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            ])
```

Also, you are missing a constraint for the height of your `PostLineItem`, something like:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:10)
```

---

In your `PostLineItem` init, you need to add constraints for the `timeLineBlock`:

```
init(labelText: String , labelHeader: String) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
    self.labelText = labelText
    self.labelHeader = labelHeader
    let tlb = timeLineBlock()
    self.addSubview(tlb)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    ])
}
```

---

Here is my version. I'm getting much better results.  Take a look...  Note, I set up my scrollView entirely in Interface Builder and just added an outlet called scrollView that points to the contentView contained by my scrollView.  That shouldn't matter.  Everything else is as you implemented.

```
class PostLineItem: UIView {


    var labelText : String!
    var labelHeader : String!

    init(labelText: String , labelHeader: String) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
        self.labelText = labelText
        self.labelHeader = labelHeader
        let tlb = timeLineBlock()
        self.addSubview(tlb)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tlb, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        ])
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        println("required public")
    }


    private func timeLineBlock() -> UIView{

        let viewNew = UIView()
        viewNew.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)


        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 20)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        titleLabel.text = labelHeader
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        viewNew.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewNew, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewNew, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewNew, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        ])

        viewNew.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return viewNew
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let guideView = UIView()
        guideView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        guideView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        scrollView.addSubview(guideView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 24),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: guideView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:4)
            ])
        guideView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        var viewFromAbove = guideView


        for post in 1...70 {

            let v = PostLineItem(labelText: "Tst", labelHeader: "Tst2")

            //let v = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
            //v.text = "Tst Now with this its working, and the constraint is fine."

            v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

            scrollView.addSubview(v)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:30)
                ])

            viewFromAbove = v
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: iPhone6 running code above]

Comment: but if i create simple UILabels the constraints take effect and it's look like as is should look like.

Comment: You need a constraint for the height of the PostLineItem.

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewFromAbove, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30) i have.. but it's not look like if i add a simple UILabel

Comment: If you create a simple label, it's height is set by the frame.  In your case, you create a `PostLineItem`, set its top, left, and width, but you don't give it a height.  See my updated answer for the constraint I think you need.

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30)  i added this constraint. But there is the same result. Both of PostLineItem are the same place they are visible if i scroll down the scrollview but they are not under each others.. :(

Comment: See updated answer.  You need additional constraints in your `PostLineItem` for the `timeLineBlock`.

Comment: updated.. i'm really don't knwo what is the error.. :(

Comment: Big update with all my code.  Take a look.  I'm getting better results.

Comment: I added a picture of my simulator run.